# If $A^3=A$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, then $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda = -1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove it to be true or false.
I really don't have any idea on how to do this.
So a little help would be very welcome.
Thank you all.

Comment: Apparently, the minmal polynmial divides $X^3-X$ ...

Comment: Hint:  if $\vec v$ is a non-zero eigenvector associated with $\lambda$, show that $A^3\vec v=\lambda^3\vec v=\lambda \vec v$.

Comment: For lulu : suppose I come to find the proof for your question, from where can I get the $\lambda =0$ or $\lambda =1$ or $\lambda =-1$?

Comment: @whytho: Remember that $\vec v$ is a ***non-zero*** vector.

Comment: Since $\vec v\neq 0$, show that, $a\vec v= b\vec v\implies a=b$.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, $A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}$ *($\vec{x}$ is Eigen vector of $A$)*

$A^3\vec{x} = A(A(A\vec{x})) = A(A(\lambda \vec{x})) = \lambda A(\lambda \vec{x}) = \lambda^2 (A\vec{x}) = \lambda^3\vec{x}$

Also,

$A^3 = A$

Thus,

$\lambda \vec{x} = \lambda^3\vec{x}$

$\lambda = \lambda^3$

$\lambda (1- \lambda ^2) = \lambda (1-\lambda )(1+\lambda ) = 0$

Thus,

$\lambda = -1\textrm{ or }0\textrm{ or }1$

Comment: Amazing, that was crystal clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your most welcome!!!